# How to call Delegate method as a selector in same delegate class

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have my custom delegate class for `UINavigationController`.

Currently i am facing issue in my `UIBarButtonItems`.

i have to define `@Selector` for each BarItem.

**So Far**
i define selector for each bar item like this:

```
SEL selector = (menu == MyMenu) ? @selector(leftSelected:) : @selector(rightSelected:);
```

the are working perfect because they are local method in my delegate class so there is no problem.

but one point i need to declare my delegate method as @Selector because its define in other viewcontroller.

here i have to define my delegate method as selector.

```
SEL selector = (menu == MenuLeft) ? @selector(leftMenuSelected:) : @selector(righttMenuSelected:);

    if (menu == MenuTwo) {
        selector = @selector(arrowMenuSelectedOut);
    }

    if ( menu == MenuTwo ){



        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:MENU_ARROW];


     UIBarButtonItem *btn=    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:selector];
          btn.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, -25.0);

        return btn;

    }
    else
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:MENU_IMAGE];


        return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:selector];
    }
```

this is my delegate method.

```
@protocol myNavigationViewControllerDeleget<NSObject>
- (void)arrowMenuSelectedOut;
@end
```

which is placed in other viewcontroller.

```
  - (void)arrowMenuSelectedOut
    {

        NSLog(@"button press");

    }
```

i want to use this arrowMenuSelectedOut method as selector from same delegate class on button press.

Comment: What issue are you having? It's not clear what problem you are having with the `@selector`?

Comment: issue is that i am unable to create @selector of delegate method as i define also if i defined in above way it is not calling

Comment: Still not clear. Update your question clearly showing how you actually create and actually use the selector. Also include any additional details such as errors.

Comment: i update the question

Comment: And what actually happens when you run this code? Why aren't you making this easier to help you?

Comment: if define as @selector it crash and *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[myNavigationViewController arrowMenuSelectedOut]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10082da00'

Comment: i  do understand the  crash becasue the  method is delegate method so it should define like  this [self.mydelegate arrowMenuSelectedOut];
but how i define it in @selector

Answer (score 2):

Based on the errors you put in the comments (they should be in the question), the problem is you are passing the wrong `target` when creating the button.

Change:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:selector];
```

to:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self.mydelegate action:selector];
```

The only thing that is changed is the `target` parameter value.

Comment: Let me check in 1 hour

Comment: I check this time no error but its stil not caling the method

Comment: Are you sure that `self.mydelegate` isn't `nil` at the time you create the button?

Comment: I m sure but will check it again :)

Comment: Yes i forget to set delegate=self; my mistake Thanks @maddy

Answer (score 1):

if you like to call delegate try it like this.

```
[self.mydelegate arrowMenuSelectedOut];
```

or in you case

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self.mydelegate action:@selector(arrowMenuSelectedOut)];
```

also check did you define you delegate properly it should not be nil.
try this

```
self.mydelegate=self;
```